# Why is XHTML1.1 dated *before* XHTML1.0 ? What is the preferred XHTML today?

Tags: xhtml, doctype, w3c, htmltidy, xhtml-1.1

I'm not clear on the status of XHTML - v1.0 versus v1.1. Can someone explain which is preferred at this point, and why?

The specs from W3C say that XHTML 1.1  *predates**  XHTML 1.0, which is very counter-intuitive, to me:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/ - W3C Recommendation 31 May 2001

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/ - W3C Recommentation, updated 1 August 2002

Also, I noted earlier today that  the latest version of [htmltidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) emits XHTML 1.0, when I request XHTML.  Hmmm....Even though the XHTML 1.1 spec is 9 years old, it's still not supported by mainstream tools. That suggests that XHTML 1.1 is either completely unnecessary or spurious.

---

Which one should I use if I am authoring pages today?  What if I am building tools - should I bother to support both?  Or do I need only one?

Thanks.

Comment: "Which one should I use if I am authoring pages today?" HTML 4.01 Strict. XHTML is dead, man.

Comment: Is that true?  Show me . . . .

Comment: http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/msiexhtml.png (I hear that version 9 will support XHTML)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the XHTML 1.0 document and click on the *[diff-marked version](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/xhtml1-diff.html)* you see that the differences are mostly/only (did not check thorough) formatting and grammar changes.

The original of this document is older than the XHTML 1.1 document, so I would think they just updated the document to comply with a newer format.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the original XHTML 1.0 documentation is older than 1.1 as answered by others,-

The XHTML 1.1 page you've linked to just describe the structure. The "modules", which actually defines the elements, are listed in http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/ and the last update is in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Not really my forte, but maybe [this](http://www.uninetnews.com/xhtml/xhtmlversions.php) article will shed some light.
Also according to [wikipedia](http://www.uninetnews.com/xhtml/xhtmlversions.php) and w3 there is no question of predating:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/  - W3C Recommentation, **26 January 2000**, revised 1 August 2002

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, XHTML 1.1 was the first fully fledged XML based version of the language. This means that XHTML 1.1 should be served with the application/xhtml+xml mime type.

XHTML 1.0 was added as an intermediate between the fully fledged XML language (XHTML 1.1) and HTML 4 (Mime type text/html).

At least that's my understanding upto this point.

Comment: XHTML 1.0 is full fledged too. The text/html RFC says you can serve "a profile of it" as text/html though. Various notes from the working group say you can served XHTML 1.1 as text/html, but this isn't supported by the spec. The whole thing is a big mess.

Comment: @Dorward, +1, especially the "big mess" part.  Standards are great, aren't they?  So many to choose from!